# Почему не работают теги с id после того, как я их вставил в body с помощью innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script src="webOSjs-0.1.0/webOS.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

  <title>IPTVPORTAL</title>

  <style>
    .center {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 40%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    table {
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      border-spacing: 0px 0px;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 3px;
    }
    
    .spacebutton {
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
    
    input:focus {
      outline: none !important;
      border: 2px solid #4169E1;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function goMain() {
      var domain = localStorage['domain'] || 'go';
      var newDomain = document.getElementById("portal").value;
      if (newDomain === domain) {
        Main.onLoad(domain);
      } else {
        localStorage['domain'] = newDomain;
        Main.onLoad(newDomain);
      }
    };

    function defaultDomain() {
      document.getElementById("portal").value = 'go';
    };
    document.onkeydown = function showSettings(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var portal = document.getElementById("portal");
      var portalFocus = portal == document.activeElement;
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37: // если нажата клавиша влево
          if (!portalFocus) {
            portal.focus();
            return false;
          }
          break;
        case 38: // если нажата клавиша вверх
          if (portalFocus) {
            return false;
          } else {
            portal.focus();
          }
          break;
        case 39: // если нажата клавиша вправо
          if (!portalFocus || portal.selectionStart == portal.value.length) {
            returnDefault.focus();
          }
          break;
        case 40: // если нажата клавиша вниз
          acceptSettings.focus();
          break;
      }
    };
  </script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="black">
  <p class="center">
    <font size="5" color="white" face="Arial">Loading...<br>Press 'OK' for settings.</font>
  </p>
  <script>
    var flag = true;

    function showSettings(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        flag = false;
        var settings_html = '\
          <table><tr><td align="center" colspan="3"><p><font size="5" color="white" face="Arial">Portal url:</font></p></td></tr>\
          <tr><td><p><input style="font-size: 18pt; text-align: right;" type="text" id="portal" size="10"></p></td>\
          <td><p class="spacebutton"><font size="5" color="white" face="Arial">.iptvportal.ru</font></p></td>\
          <td><p><input type="button" style="font-size: 18pt;" onClick="defaultDomain()" id="returnDefault" value="Set to default"></input></p></td></tr>\
          <tr><td align="center" colspan="3"><p><input type="button" style="font-size: 18pt;" onClick="goMain()" id="acceptSettings" value="Apply"></input></p></td></tr></table>\
         ';
        document.body.innerHTML = settings_html;
      }
    }

    function start_player() {
      if (flag) {
        Main.onLoad(localStorage['domain'] || 'go');
      }
    }
    setTimeout(start_player, 1500);
    addEventListener("keydown", showSettings);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Стили почему-то сработали на вставленный код, а вот скрипт отрабатывать не хочет, словно не видит эти теги с их id. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Что значит "не работают"?

Comment: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: Main is not defined"_

Comment: @igor, ну, никак не отрабатывают. Там при нажатии на кнопку "Set to default" должно поле "portal" заполнится текстом "go", но не заполняется. При нажатии на кнопку "Save" ничего не происходит.

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в вопросе.

Comment: @Igor, это ругается на отсутствие локального main.js, который я сюда не добавил. Там есть функция Main. У меня в приложении он есть и на него ругаться не должно. У меня это всё работало, когда было в двух отдельных html, но вот надо их объединить в один и такие проблемы со скриптом появились.

Comment: Щелкните по черному фону мышью, нажмите Enter и кнопку "Set to default". Появилось "go" в инпуте?

Comment: @Igor, хм, почему-то появилось, а у меня на реальном устройстве не отрабатывает... В браузере открыл, там тоже работает, только стили криво применились... А на смарт тв не хочет.

Comment: @Grundy "А как узнал, что золото у меня, а?" "Свой среди чужих, чужой среди своих" - как узнал, что это дубликат?

Comment: Это не дубликат, т.к. тут у меня скрипт находится в head, а innerHTML я делаю в body. В том ответе чувак добавил div, а затем заменил его тем, что добавил в innerHTML, у меня же иная ситуация, и как оказалось, в браузере у меня работает, но просто на смарт тв почему-то функции не отрабатывают...

Comment: @Igor, так он ж innerHTML у body меняет

Comment: @Grundy но `onClick`-и прямо там прописаны

Comment: @Igor, тогда вероятно не дубликат :-)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров, добавляй в свой код больше отладочной информации и смотри консоль браузера, в котором не работает, возможно там есть ошибки